# Searching multiple words in many blocks of data

Tags: c++, python

I have to search about 100 words in blocks of data (20000 blocks approximately) and each block consists of about 20 words. The blocks should be returned in the decreasing order of the number of matches. The brute force technique is very cumbersome because you have to search for all the 100 words one by one and then combine the number of related searches in a complicated manner. Is there any other algorithm which allows to search multiple words at the same time and store the number of matching words?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) algorithm to search for all 100 words at a time. There are several implementations available [here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=aho%20corasick) and on [github](https://gist.github.com/search?q=aho%20corasick).

Answer (score 0):

Why no consider using multithreading to store the result? Make an array with size equal to number of blocks, then each thread count for the result in one block, then the thread writes the result to the corresponding entry in the array. Later on you sort the array by decreasing order then you get the result.